# Variable or constant expression required , Pascal

Tags: file, delphi, variables, constants, pascal

[constant vs variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4V7z.jpg)

Hi, im currently working with files. Its File of Char that is declared globally. Im trying to find any letter (A,b, etc.) in the file of char and i know there is only one character in each line and i want to change it to dot. (Variable  TECKA - DOT) 
When i want to write char, it says "Constant expression expected", but when i change it to constant (code in comment section), it says "Variable required". What am i doing wrong here? 
Thanks for reply.

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var znak,tecka:char;
begin
  tecka:='.';
  assignfile(f,'Znaky.dat');
  reset(f);
  While not eof(f) do begin
    read(f,znak);
    Case znak of 'a'..'z','A'..'Z':
      seek(f,filepos(f)-1);
      Write(f,tecka);           // write(f,'.');
    end;
  end;
  closefile(f);
end;
```

Comment: Please don't put code in an image, just paste the code as text in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're doing wrong has nothing to do with the line `write(f,tecka);`, but everything to do with block rules in pascal.

If you want to compiler to stop complaining you need to change the case statement to:

```
case znak of 
  'a'..'z','A'..'Z': begin
    seek(f,filepos(f)-1);
    write(f,tecka);
  end;
end; {case}
```

The problem is that the case statement expects one or more constant expressions (e.g. `'a'..'z'`) after the `of`. After a `:` you can only put a single statement or a begin end block. Because you're putting 2 statements after the `:` Pascal wants to interpret the second statement as another case clause (e.g.: `'0'..'9':`) which it isn't.

If you want to put multiple statements in a section you must always use a begin-end block.

This is also a gotcha in if-statements:

```
if x then 
  statement1;
  statement2;  <-- statement2 will always be executed, because it's not part of the if
```

This should be:

```
if x then begin
  statement1;
  statement2;     <-- statement2 depends on x.
end;
```

It's for this reason that many people always use begin-end blocks.
Even if there is a single statement.
If you change code later you just put your extra statements in the begin-end block that's already there and you can't forget to put it in.

Note that the assignfile-reset-seek etc calls are quite outdated.
In Delphi it's more efficient to use a stringlist to do your processing.

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var 
  MyText: TStringList;
  i,a: integer;
  znak,tecka:char;
const
  Alpha = 'a'..'z','A'..'Z';
  Filename = 'Znaky.dat';
begin
  tecka:='.';
  MyText:= TStringlits.create;
  MyText.LoadFromFile(Filename);
  //loop though all lines.
  for i:= 0 to MyText.Lines.Count-1 do begin
    //loop though every char in a line (string chars start counting from 1 !)
    for a:= 1 to Length(MyText.Lines[i]) do begin
      case MyText.Lines[i][a] of 
        Alpha: begin
          MyText.Lines[i][a]:= tecka;
        end;
      end; {case} 
    end; {for}
  end; {for}
  MyText.WriteToFile(Filename);
end;
```

This is more performant because you only do disk IO twice instead of many times.

Personal nitpick: please don't capitalize keywords like `case` and `while`, this is Pascal, not VB.

Comment: @Johan: please put every `begin` on its own line, aligned with `end`. This is Delphi, not Java or K&R C. <vbg>